# HTML dropdown box

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my dropdown box. Somehow I managed to create a navigational bar and then added keys to it. I made a drop down box on the "About" window. And it seems to work. But i have problem related to dropdown box. I am having trouble creating a second dropdown box. And it sometimes changes the navigational bar.
Misplace the positon and other type of errors. Can you show me an example of a dropdown box on the "HOME" button? Here is my code. plzzz help me.

```css
/* Building navigation bar */

ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
/* Building about dropdown and the dropdown content */

.container {
  width: 15em;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
/*added lines*/

.dropdown-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  /*font-color will be red*/
}
/*added lines ends here*/

.paragraphs {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#file:///C:/Users/Nabil/Desktop/web/YouBox/main.html#style.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <a href="#Server.html">Server</a>
          <a href="#hahahaha.html">Origins</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <p class="paragraphs"><strong>mymash.com<br> 
    Top vs games - pictures in Bahrain!  <br>
     Who looks mind blowing? Lets see, Vote your favourite photo!</strong>
    <br>or you can add new pictures of yourself to challenge someone <a href="#test">HERE!</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is a boox?

Comment: use 
ul{ padding-left:0px;} for proper arrangement of dropdown sub fields.

Comment: you can use some nice libraries like bootstrap which provides implementation for similar functionality. http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp this is an example.

Comment: try this.here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqja5ven/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here you see the ' .dropdown-content css hide the display of `<a>` tags**

```
.dropdown-content {  
          position: absolute;  
          display: none;       <-----------------  hide  contents  
          background-color: black;
          color: white;           
}
```

**then while hover**

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
          display: block;  <----  make visible the contents  
}  
li a:hover { 
             background-color: red; <---- change the background color to red
}
```

try this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    /* Building navigation bar */ 

    ul {
        text-align: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
      background-color: black;
      display: block;
    }

    li a { 
             text-decoration: none;
       padding: 14px 20px;
       color: white;
      
    }

    li a:hover { 
                 background-color: red;
    }

    li { 
             display: inline;
    }

    /* Building about dropdown and the dropdown content */ 

    .container { 
               width: 15em;
    }

    .dropdown { 
            position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content { 
              position: absolute;
        display: none;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
           
    } 

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
              display: block;
    }

     /*added lines*/
    .dropdown-content a{
      text-decoration:none;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
        position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
     
    }
    .dropdown-content a:hover{
      background-color:red;/*font-color will be red*/
    }
    /*added lines ends here*/

    .paragraphs { 
        text-align:center;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <ul>
       <div class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#file:///C:/Users/Nabil/Desktop/web/YouBox/main.html#style.html">Home</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content"><ul>
           <a href="#page1.html">item1</a>
        <a href="#page2.html">item2</a>
        </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
     <div class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#about.html">About</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content"><ul>
           <a href="#Server.html">Server</a>
        <a href="#hahahaha.html">Origins</a>
        </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <p class="paragraphs"><strong>mymash.com<br> 
        Top vs games - pictures in Bahrain!  <br>
         Who looks mind blowing? Lets see, Vote your favourite photo!</strong><br>
         or you can add new pictures of yourself to challenge someone <a href="#test">HERE!</a></p>
      <hr>
       
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Can you tell me something about your code. I am a bit confused. As you can see once the person hover "dropdown" he will get to see the "dropdown-content" but as you can see We have used the "dropdown-content" in two places. In the "Home" button and the "About" button. So how does the HTML or CSS knows which drop down menu have to be unblocked when the use hovers it. Because they all have the same name.... If i hover on "About" button, It will show the "Dropdown-content" but "dropdown-content" is also used in "Home" button. Why doesn't it appears there too?

Comment: < a > item1</a>  < a > item2</a> tags are  live under the 'Home <li>' and <a> server</a> <a>orgins<a>   tags are live under the 'About <li>' ,here what css doing is  just change the backgound color to red and make the below tags <a> visible while hover.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

li a { 
         text-decoration: none;
   padding: 14px 20px;
   color: white;
  
}

li a:hover { 
             background-color: red;
}

li { 
         display: inline;
}

/* Building about dropdown and the dropdown content */ 

.container { 
           width: 15em;
}

.dropdown { 
        position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content { 
          position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
       
} 

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
          display: block;
}

 /*added lines*/
.dropdown-content a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
  padding:10px 16px;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover{
  background-color:red;/*font-color will be red*/
}
/*added lines ends here*/

.paragraphs { 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#file:///C:/Users/Nabil/Desktop/web/YouBox/main.html#style.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
 <div class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#about.html">About</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  
       <a href="#Server.html">Server</a>
    <a href="#hahahaha.html">Origins</a>
    
      </div>
 </div>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <p class="paragraphs"><strong>mymash.com<br> 
    Top vs games - pictures in Bahrain!  <br>
     Who looks mind blowing? Lets see, Vote your favourite photo!</strong><br>
     or you can add new pictures of yourself to challenge someone <a href="#test">HERE!</a></p>
  <hr>
```

here is jsfiddle: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pqja5ven/)